# Deploying Heroku ap to multiple URLs

Tags: git, heroku, directory, hosting, config

I am attempting to deploy a heroku app to multiple URLs. I have copied the app directory to a copy directory with a different name and typed heroku create to get an app name. However, when I type git remote -v, it lists the git directory for the original app. I changed the file .git/config so that git remote -v shows the correct (new) git directory, but when I go to commit it, I see my list of commits from the previous app. I am worried that when I type git push heroku master, it will overwrite my original app. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is good practice to copy the actual directory.

Try `git clone -l ./oldRepoDir newRepoDir` to actually make a copy of the directory into an entirely new repository.

Reference: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html